# Mentally challenged as differently abled

Tags: politeness, political-correctness

Can we politely refer to somebody who is mentally challenged but leading an almost normal life upon professional support as differently abled?

Comment: https://youtu.be/vuEQixrBKCc?t=308 one could argue for a long time over this one. SCNR

Comment: Not if you want people to know what you're talking about.

Comment: I thought "mentally challenged" which replaced the once medical terms: "retard", "idiot" and the later,  "slow learner", was the PC form? There's also *intellectually disabled*, but I find that more offensive and insensitive.

Comment: Is the person in question an adult who is aware of their limitations, or a child still attending school? Likewise, are you speaking to the school principal, a group of friends or workmates.  If you can answer, could you please include this information in your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The problem with all such terms is that they tend to suffer from what I'll call 'euphemism rot'.  In other words, what was once politically correct gradually comes to be thought of as offensive and a replacement term has to be invented. Also, the phrases differ in different countries.

In Britain, I have certainly heard both the terms you mention. Speaking from personal impressions, 'mentally challenged' has now passed its sell-by date through being used by young people as an insult. On the other hand 'differently abled' still sounds inoffensive.

"Differently abled" is a wider term than "mentally challenged" and I think more recent. It seems inoffensive but a little clumsy to me and, if it throws scorn on anyone, then it is on the speaker rather than the person being described..

Really, you need to think of your audience/readership. For instance journalists will use one term, organisations that provide assistance will use another and the general public a third.

You say 'can we politely refer'. My answer is Yes, but it depends on our role and who we're speaking to.

Finally, are you using 'differently abled' in conversation with someone who already knows the person's situation or are you expecting a stranger to know precisely what you mean? The former would be served by 'differently abled', the latter would not.

Note: I think the final answer must be opinion-based, generational, context dependent and related to location. It would help if you could be more specific about these aspects.

Comment: I mean using the term differently abled while conversing with an individual or group having the knowledge of the person's situation and stranger is not included.

Comment: @SyamKumar.V -  I'm no expert but, in that case I think that 'differently abled' would be the safest term to use. Thereafter you can see what the others habitually say. If there's a consensus you can adopt that.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK. I very much like your term "euphemism rot", which shows how you have to keep abreast to avoid offending people. The term in France for "disabled" is "handicappé", which can cause shock among Anglo-Saxons. But there's very little difference between the essential meaning of the two terms, and there are two different languages here.

Comment: When it comes right down to it - everyone is "Differently abled". That is one of those phrases that has so obscured its meaning as to have become meaningless. And, in North America, that phrase tends to be used for physical rather than mental handicaps.

Comment: I'm not lazy, I'm motivationally challenged.

Comment: There is nothing "abled" about having trouble crossing the street.

Comment: So Stephen Hawking has no abilities?

Comment: "Euphemism rot" is lovely. As to whether "differently abled" is polite, is such verbal tiptoeing really polite?  I know three people with children with Down's Syndrome, and they are all forthright about the condition.  The OP explained that he was asking about a term to be used among people who knew about the condition.    If everyone in the group knows about the condition, why not just refer to "Mary" (let's call her Mary) without adding "differently abled" or some other phrase?  And, if you know the official cause, e.g., mild Down's Syndrome or Parkinson's, just say it if you need to.

Comment: Unfortunately, "euphemism rot" has ceased to enjoy the support of connotation-sensitive persons. The current approved term is "differently catabolized nomenclature."

Comment: @SvenYargs - Haha! :-D

Comment: @ab2 - You've inspired me to add the definition of 'euphemism rot' to Urban Dictionary.  If it gets past their moderators, then in a day or to it should appear. FAME AT LAST - Mwhaha!

Answer (score 1):

In the US, by Federal statute [per Public Law 111-256](http://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/782769) "Rosa's Law", the American Psychiatric Association in its Diagnostic and Statistical Manual for Mental Disorders (DSM-5) has officially replaced the term 'mental retardation' with  'intellectual disability'.

Frankly, if I heard 'differently abled' here in Canada without going into more detail I would normally assume a physical challenge rather than a mental one.

And that's what I dislike about these fluffy, innocuous PC terms - they don't tell anything. "Differently abled", relating to a physical impairment, could mean has slight difficulty with walking, or paraplegic. they invariably need clarification if the type of disability is at all relevant to the conversation. I recognize, and agree, that terms need to be sensitive to the person being described. But no matter what term is adopted - the cruel people of the world will turn it around into an insult in short order.

Tell me a person has Autism-spectrum issues, and I will have a clue. Tell me they are differently abled and you've told me almost nothing. And if you didn't need me to know something specific - then why bring it up in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

There's no hint of politeness in either mentally challenged or differently abled. However, avoid outdated terms like “handicapped”, “crippled”, or “retarded.

> Sometimes just saying the right thing or making a small gesture that
>   acknowledges their independence and value goes a long way toward
>   reducing discrimination and improving daily life.
>
> Be aware that  many people with disabilities dislike jargony,
>   euphemistic terms like "physically challenged" and "differently
>   abled."

[Terminology Tips/Disability Etiquette](http://www.unitedspinal.org/disability-etiquette/)............(unitedspinal.org)

Comment: I don't think "handicapped" and "crippled" are outdated yet. In a parking context, "handicapped parking" seems a neutral phrase to me, and you can definitely find people who prefer to refer to themselves as "crippled" rather than "disabled."